# fineuploader chunk signature v4

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

While trying to upload large file(chunk upload) in signature v4 I get the following error from AWS :
SignatureDoesNotMatch The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

**FineUploader headers:**
{"headers":"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20180214T003940Z\n20180214/eu-west-3/s3/aws4_request\nPOST\n/foldername/oovoosdk-android-2.3.0.113-1.zip\nuploads=\nhost:https://test.s3.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-acl:private\nx-amz-content-sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149c897ydu27sas88e56e4649b934ca495991b7852b855\nx-amz-date:20180214T003940Z\nx-amz-meta-filename:oovoosdk-android-2.3.0.113-1.zip\nx-amz-meta-qqfilename:oovoosdk-android-2.3.0.113-1.zip\n\nhost;x-amz-acl;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-meta-filename;x-amz-meta-qqfilename\ne3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8b92427ae41e464hd783a3dc752b855"}

**CanonicalRequest**

POST
/foldername/oovoosdk-android-2.3.0.113-1.zip
uploads=
host:test.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-acl:private
x-amz-content-sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149c897ydu27sas88e56e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
x-amz-date:20180214T010103Z
x-amz-meta-filename:oovoosdk-android-2.3.0.113-1.zip
x-amz-meta-qqfilename:oovoosdk-android-2.3.0.113-1.zip

host;x-amz-acl;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-meta-filename;x-amz-meta-qqfilename
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8b92427ae41e464hd783a3dc752b855

Non chunk upload working fine in signature v4.

**v4 signature generation code**

StringtoSign --> headers from fine uploader

```
public static String getSignature(AWS_Key_Set__c awsKeySet,String StringtoSign) 
{ String HASH_ALGORITHM = 'SHA-256'; 
String MAC_ALGORITHM = 'HmacSHA256'; 
String SIGNATURE_VERSION = 'AWS4'; 
String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'; 
String serviceName='s3'; 
Datetime dt = Datetime.now();
String region='eu-west-3'; 
String todayDate = dt.formatGmt('yyyyMMdd');
String now = todayDate + 'T' + dt.formatGmt('HHmmss') + 'Z'; 
Blob keyDate = Crypto.generateMac(MAC_ALGORITHM, Blob.valueOf(todayDate), Blob.valueof(SIGNATURE_VERSION + awsKeySet.AWS_Secret_Key__c)); 
Blob keyRegion = Crypto.generateMac(MAC_ALGORITHM, Blob.valueOf(region), keyDate); 
Blob keyService = Crypto.generateMac(MAC_ALGORITHM, Blob.valueOf(serviceName.toLowerCase()), keyRegion); Blob keyCredentials = Crypto.generateMac(MAC_ALGORITHM, Blob.valueOf('aws4_request'), keyService); 
return EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateMac(MAC_ALGORITHM, Blob.valueOf(StringtoSign), keyCredentials)); 
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question.

Comment: `host:https://test.s3.amazonaws.com` seems incorrect, as it seems like it should be `host:test.s3.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: Did u find answer? I have same error and can't figure it out.